# Na página Analisar é necessário fazer scroll para o botão "Meta Reviews" ficar visível

Tags: novo-recurso, layout

O botão <kbd>Meta Reviews</kbd> está localizado logo abaixo do conteúdo principal da página [Analisar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review), ficando escondido(pelo menos no meu monitor).

Não seria preferível colocá-lo na parte superior, junto ao botão <kbd>Ferramentas</kbd>, de forma a que todo o conteúdo importante ficasse visível, sem necessidade de fazer *scroll*?